# separating text from a single textbox into 2 php variables using javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I have been racking my brain around this for a few hours. Basically I have a div that displays user info from a database:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['email']) && ($_SESSION['userID'])) {

$sql = "SELECT * FROM user_accounts WHERE email='" . $_SESSION['email'] . "' AND user_id=" . $_SESSION['userID'] ;
$userRecordSet = $_dbConn->query($sql);

if ($userRecordSet != NULL) {
    $userRow = $userRecordSet->getrow();
    $firstName = $userRow['first_name'];
    $lastName = $userRow['last_name'];

    }
```

}

The first and last name are then placed into the div and displayed to the user.

```
<div id="nameChange" title="Click to edit"><?=$firstName?> <?=$lastName?></div>
```

when the user clicks on this DIV element it converts into a text box, and displays the contents of the user's first and last name taken from the DIV. here is the Jquery to support the above.

```
//execute when nameChange DIV is clicked
        $("#nameChange").click(function(){  

                //check if there are any existing input elements
                if ($(this).children('input').length == 0){


                    $("#save").css("display", "inline");

                    //variable that contains input HTML to replace
                    var inputbox = "<input type='text' class='inputbox' name='userName' value=\""+$(this).text()+"\">"; 
                    //insert the HTML intp the div
                    $(this).html(inputbox);         

                    //automatically give focus to the input box     
                    $("this .inputbox").focus();


                }               
        });
```

Doing this creates an issue with the database because I want the first and last name to go into separate columns but after it is converted into a text box, the contents are placed into a single variable.  now for the question.

how can I parse through the text box and assign 2 separate variables for the first and last name?

Comment: You mean parse it while clicking "SAVE" ?

Comment: yes exactly... the text box carries 2 variables from the database and displayed into 1 text box (php will recognize this as 1 variable). now in order to save they have to be parsed back into 2 seperate variables

Comment: How would you handle a situation where the first or last name has spaces?

Comment: ok, massimo, but what if my name consists of 2 words or my surname?

Comment: yup, you guys are right. the more i think about this the more i am thinking it would be best to just display seperate input elements.!!

Comment: That would be the only solution. I think. Or you can tell the user to follow a specific format like _Last Name, First Name_ then you can do the parsing solution.

Comment: Thanks for all the input guys, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes that your final parsing to the database is done with `php`.

here are two function I use to get the first and last name form a text input:

```
//returns first name form full name input
public function FirstName($input)
    {   
        $name = explode(" ",$input);
        $howmany = count($name);
        if($howmany != '1')
            {
            if($howmany == '2')
                {   
                    $firstname = $name[0];
                    return $firstname;
                }
                    if($howmany == '3')
                {   
                    $firstname = $name[0]." ".$name[1];
                    return $firstname;
                }
            }

        return false;   
    }
//returns last name from full name input
public function LastName($input)
    {   
        $name = explode(" ",$input);
        $howmany = count($name);
        if($howmany != '1')
            {   
                $last = $howmany -1;
                $lastname = $name[$last];
                return $lastname;
            }
        return false;   
    }
```

This takes into account people that have two first names such as " mary lynn"

Comment: This could do it, but there's a problem with this solution. In case the last name is composed of two words like _Dela Cerna_ or something else, then you can only get the last word.

Comment: @dunli   Yep, he would have to make the assumptions that work best for him. Could be a 2, 3, 4, or 5 part name. this works well for me and can easily be adapted to do more I think. But you have a good point.